# theharvester.py "No such file or directory"

Tags: vmware, kali-linux

I just installed Kali Linux as a virtual machine in VMware Fusion, and I was following along in Patrick Engebretson's *The Basics of Hacking and Penetration Testing, 2nd Edition*, in which I was prompted to open "The Harvester" in Kali. As instructed in the book, I tried the following command at top level in the terminal:

```
./theharvester.py –d syngress.com –l 10 –b google
```

To which the system reported:

```
bash: ./theharvester.py: No such file or directory
```

Wondering if for some reason the software just wasn't included in the version of Kali I downloaded, I attempted to `locate theharvester` on the system. This returned a multitude of files under `/user/share` and a directory at `/usr/bin/theharvester` but no contained files. As expected though, `theharvester.py` was not on the list. I then tried uninstalling the current software/files and reinstalling with `apt-get`, just to get the same `No such file or directory` error.

What do I need to do to get `theharvester.py` (and any other missing files) on my system in the right spot?

**UPDATE:**

Just running the command `theharvester` does indeed return the following screen:
[image]

Comment: Try typing `theharvester` without `./` and `.py`.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: Tool got renamed and put on binary search path: just try `./theharvester.py –dsyngress.com –l 10 –b google`

Comment: Uhh, that's the same command I had listed above...?

Comment: Uh, I meant `theharvester –dsyngress.com –l 10 –b google`. Sorry.

Comment: It just ignores the arguments and shows the same screen as above. :/

Comment: Try `$(which theharvester).py –dsyngress.com –l 10 –b google`

Comment: Returns the file not found error.

Comment: Are each of the arguments you are trying to use described in the Usage text? I don't see `-l` in your screenshot, but it might be off the screen.

Also try:
`theharvester –d syngress.com –l 10 –b google`

With or without `-l 10`, depending on whether it shows up in the Usage. Note the space after `-d`. Sometimes important, sometimes not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having reviewed a version of the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/theharvester/source/browse/trunk/theHarvester.py) that matches the version number in your screenshot, I believe this will work:

`theharvester –d syngress.com –l 10 –b google`
CORRECTION: `theharvester –d syngress.com –b google`
The OP's version had no `-l` flag.

The original command you tried to run was prefixed with `./` and suffixed with `.py`, which means: look for `theharvester.py` in the current directory and execute it. Based on your locate, the binary is actually named `theharvester` and is located in `/usr/bin/`. So, as @TNW pointed out, the script was renamed and installed into `/usr/bin/` instead of wherever the book's author assumed your current working directory was. Because `/usr/bin/` is almost certainly in your binary lookup `$PATH`, the `./` is not appropriate.

Also important is the space between `-d` and `syngress.com` due to the way the script is parsing arguments. It looks like the space was present in the original command you tried, but not in some of the other commenters' suggestions.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Unfortunately, this just results in the same screenshot that I included in the question.

Comment: Correction: omitting the `-1 10` per your comment above worked. Thanks a bunch. I'll go ahead and accept your answer and reward the bounty. You might consider appending your comment on the question into your answer since it turned out to be the solution. Thanks again!